# Random Forest not working in opencv python (cv2)

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, classification, random-forest

I can't seem to correctly pass in the parameters to train a Random Forest classifier in opencv from python.

I wrote an implementation in C++ which worked correctly, but do not get the same results in python.

I found some sample code here: http://fossies.org/linux/misc/opencv-2.4.7.tar.gz:a/opencv-2.4.7/samples/python2/letter_recog.py

which seems to indicate that you should pass in the parameters in a dict.  Here is the code I am using:

```
rtree_params = dict(max_depth=11, min_sample_count=5, use_surrogates=False, max_categories=15, calc_var_importance=False, n_active_vars=0, max_num_of_trees_in_the_forest=1000, termcrit_type=cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER)
classifier = cv2.RTrees()
classifier.train(train_data, cv2.CV_ROW_SAMPLE, label_data, params=rtree_params);
```

I can tell that the classifier is getting trained correctly, but it is not nearly as accurate as the one I trained with the same parameters in C++.  I'm fairly certain that the parameters are getting acknowledged, because I get different results when I tweak the values.

I did notice that when I output the classifier to a file, it **only has one tree**.  I'm pretty sure this is the problem.  I looked at the openCV implementation:

http://www.code.opencv.org/svn/gsoc2012/denoising/trunk/opencv-2.4.2/modules/ml/src/rtrees.cpp

Given my parameters, it should output a forest with 1000 trees.  I tried setting the `max_num_of_trees_in_the_forest` arguments to all sorts of crazy values, and it didn't change OpenCV's behaviour.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this will help much, but I believe:

```
n_active_vars=0
```

should be

```
nactive_vars=0
```

Also, you may wish to try experimenting with the term_crit parameter.
For example, try adding:

```
term_crit=(cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER,1000,1)
```

into your dictionary.

I believe this will set the criteria to terminate when 1000 trees are added into the forest.

Comment: That second suggestion seemed to work, but how did you figure it out? Was it just an educated guess looking at how some of the other classifiers are trained?

The CvRTreeParams data structure is defined here:

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/random_trees.html#cvrtparams-cvrtparams

How do you figure out the mapping between the C++ type and its python representation?

Comment: I searched in the cv2.so file for the text symbols and did not see max_num_of_trees_in_the_forest so then went digging through the C++ source for other ways of setting this.  As far as I am aware, the mapping is automatically generated so it is just a matter of experience/practice to gradually learn how it is mapped across.  It does not seem very satisfactory to me - although I do much prefer using Python bindings than the C++ ones in general.