# Python OpenCV Random trees parameters

Tags: python, opencv, random-forest

I am trying to create an image classifier based on RandomTrees from OpenCV (version 2.4). Right now, I initialize everything likes this:

```
    self.model = cv.RTrees()
    max_num_trees=10
    max_error=1
    max_d=5
    criteria=cv.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER+cv.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS
    parameters = dict(max_depth=max_d, min_sample_count=5, use_surrogates=False, nactive_vars=0, 
                      term_crit=(criteria, max_num_trees, max_error))
    self.model.train(dataset, cv.CV_ROW_SAMPLE, responses, params=parameters)
```

I did it by looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20252323/random-forest-not-working-in-opencv-python-cv2) question. The only problem is, whatever I change in the parameters, classification always remains the same (and wrong). Since the python documentation on this is very very scarce, I have no choice but to ask here what to do and how to check what I am doing. How to get the number of trees it generates and all the other things that are explained for C++ but not for Python - like train error? For example, I tried:

```
self.model.tree_count
self.model.get_tree_count()
```

but got an error every time. Also, am I doing the termination criteria initialization correctly?